# Android concept of the timestamps in contact, phone, emailaddress and so on

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a few questions about the concept of androids timestamps. I want to synchronize my contacts but only if the timestamp of the contacts detail in the android is older than that one in my database.

My questions. Is there a timestamp for each detail like phonenumer, emailaddress and address. And who to check it? I tried it for ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STATUS_TIMESTAMP which is always null.

Any ideas? The Android Api tells me that there should be a timestamp (long).

Thanksfor your help.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. The field you're talking about is a convenience for someone who wants to stamp the row with the last time the raw contact's status was updated. I doubt that the Android system itself is using it.

I think that Contacts synchronization assumes that Google Contacts is the source of all knowledge, and the Android system is just a reflection of it. If something changes on Android, and it hasn't changed in Google Contacts, then it gets uploaded to Google Contacts. Changes on Google Contacts overwrite anything on Android.

On the whole, I'm suspicious of synchronization based on timestamps, because it has a tendency to get screwed up.

Are you trying to replace the google.com sync adapter with your own? You're a brave person!

Answer (score 0):

> CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP

is added in the API 18. The same can be used.